# Getting the parent of a element in a .json file

Tags: python, json, parent

I have a `.json` file with a lot of elements. I would like to be able to search for a element value and check it's parent/what the element is inside of.
Here I have a sample of my `.json` file.

```
{
  "users": {
    "123467890": {
      "lvl": 100,
      "xp": 1000,
      "lastMessage": 91.996059
    }
  }
}
```

So lets say I chose `lvl` as my element. How would I get it's parent's value without hardcoding it?

Comment: Are the keys of interest always directly below users/N or is the dictionary arbitrarily nested?

Comment: You should clarify if the thing you are querying for is a named attribute such as "lvl" or if it's the value of a named attribute e.g. "lvl" with value 51.

Comment: User has a element called lvl. The value of lvl is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the dictionary and add the keys that contain a value["lvl"] of 100.

```py
d = {
  "users": {
    "123467890": {
      "lvl": 100,
      "xp": 1000,
      "lastMessage": 91.996059
    },
    "test": {
      "lvl": 1,
      "xp": 0,
      "lastMessage": 91.996059
    },
  }
}

lvl_100_users = []
for user_id, properties in d["users"].items():
    print(f"User ID: {user_id}; Properties: {properties}")
    if properties["lvl"] == 100:
        lvl_100_users.append(user_id)

print(lvl_100_users)
```

Outputs:

```sh
User ID: 123467890; Properties: {'lvl': 100, 'xp': 1000, 'lastMessage': 91.996059}
User ID: test; Properties: {'lvl': 1, 'xp': 0, 'lastMessage': 91.996059}
['123467890']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, obj refers to your json object and key refers to the "lvl" (your element).

```
 def json_extract(obj, key):
    """Recursively fetch values from nested JSON."""
    arr = []
    def extract(obj, arr, key, parent=None):
        """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree."""
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            if key in obj.keys():
                arr.append(parent)
                return parent
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    extract(v, arr, key, k)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item, arr, key, parent)
        return arr
    values = extract(obj, arr, key)
    return values
```